# Chrome extension manifest 2 sandboxing example

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

Anyone knows a complete example as referred from [Sandboxing Eval Doc](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/sandboxingEval.html)

Comment: See "Sandboxed Frame" at [Samples](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/samples.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Chrome has a [github repo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples) with lots of extension examples.  There are two sandboxing examples:

- [This one](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/sandbox) builds Handlebars templates (which require `eval`) inside a *hidden* sandboxed iframe and then passes data out to the extension at large using `postMessage`.
- [This other one](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/sandboxed-content) has a *visible* sandboxed iframe which builds a framed page using unsafe techniques.

Note that these examples require a minimum version of 23, which has not yet reached the stable channel.

Comment: One thing that I didn't get from these examples is that you can not perform cross-site reqests from sandboxed pages. That was a realy bad surprisse.

Comment: The links are now showing 404

Answer (score 0):

[The link to the complete example, you were searching for, is here.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/sandbox)

Comment: The link is now showing 404